# How to highlight string of QTextedit in android using Qt 5.3?

Tags: android, qt, qtextedit

can anyone help me How to highlight string of QTextedit in android using Qt 5.3 ?

***---update----***

in android native textedit when you touch and hold word , the word highlighted , i want highlight string in QTextEdit like this...

Comment: Oh... that sounds very different from what I thought. You should update your question with that extra information.

Comment: Please update your question with the information @Mitch asked for.